# Looping through ListView twice

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I have an activity with a custom `ListView`.  I have two `TextView`s in each row, one of them contains static text and the other contains numbers which are randomly changed on a `Button` press.  I need to save the data of both `TextView`s in two seperate `ArrayList`s (if the value of the number `TextView` is not 0).  The values are being stored inside the ArrayLists as I wish, however the records are being inserted twice; such that when I loop through the ArrayList and show them in a Toast I get twice the value of the rows entered.

Below are my code snippets:

**On Button click adding value of Number TextView**

```
holder.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            int temp = numPickerValues.get(position);
            temp += 1;
            numPickerValues.set(position, temp);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
holder.num.setText(String.valueOf(numPickerValues.get(position)));
```

**Adding values of non-0 TextViews to ArrayList**

```
    if(!holder.num.getText().equals("0"))
    {
        materialNames.add(holder.txt.getText().toString());
        materialAmounts.add(holder.num.getText().toString());
    }
```

This is the fun part.
I debugged the application to check where the problem lies and I found out it is looping inside the `ListView` twice and thus storing the values twice inside the ArrayLists, however I do not have the values duplicated in my `ListView`.  The duplicated value of one TextView is being shown after another, so it is not exactly looping twice, otherwise the values would be separated by others.

Any idea of what is going on?

**Displaying values**

```
public String getTest()
{
    test= "";

    for(String i : materialNames)
    {   
        test = test + " " + i;  
    }
    return test;
}
```

*Then I call the above method from another activity on Button Click*

```
btnConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                 Toast tt = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), adapter.getTest(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                 tt.show();
            }
        });
```

**Custom Adapter class**

```
public class MaterialListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
ViewHolder holder;
int counter = 0;
String test = null;
TextView txtNum;

private ArrayList<MaterialClass> data;
private ArrayList<Integer> numPickerValues;
private ArrayList<String> materialNames;
private ArrayList<String> materialAmounts;

public static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public static Dialog dialog;
String materialName;

public MaterialListViewAdapter(Context applicationContext,
        int materialdialogcontent, ArrayList<MaterialClass> materials) 
{
    this.data = materials;
    this.numPickerValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    this.materialNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    this.materialAmounts = new ArrayList<String>();

    int size = Material.materialList.size();

    for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        this.numPickerValues.add(0);
    }
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() 
{
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) 
{
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) 
{
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.materialdialogcontent, null);

        holder.txt = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMaterialName);
        holder.add = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        holder.sub = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnSub);
        holder.num = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtNum);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txt.setText(data.get(position).getName());       

    holder.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            int temp = numPickerValues.get(position);
            temp += 1;
            numPickerValues.set(position, temp);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    holder.sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            int temp = numPickerValues.get(position);
            temp -= 1;
            numPickerValues.set(position, temp);
            notifyDataSetChanged(); 
        }
    });

    holder.num.setText(String.valueOf(numPickerValues.get(position)));

    if(!holder.num.getText().equals("0"))
    {
        materialNames.add(holder.txt.getText().toString());
        materialAmounts.add(holder.num.getText().toString());
    }

    return convertView;
}

public String getTest()
{
    test= "";

    for(String i : materialNames)
    {   
             test = test + " " + i;
    }
    return test;
}

private static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView txt;
    Button add;
    Button sub;
    TextView num;
}
```

}

Comment: ARe you using custom adapter for listview?

Comment: Yes it is a custom adapter.

Comment: Ok..then post your code for that

Comment: the problem is there when you have add a value in "numPickerValues" in for loop.

Comment: That for loop is setting the values of all TextViews to 0 before the user even clicks anything

Comment: Could you explain further @PiyushGupta

Comment: @ClaireG my means to say that your getView method called twice.

Comment: So what is the solution? Because I cannot understand what you mean by "its being called twice"

Comment: try to call your loop for add "0" in to getView() method... rather than in COnstrucor.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35327/discussion-between-piyush-gupta-and-claireg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!holder.num.getText().equals("0"))
{
    materialNames.add(holder.txt.getText().toString());
    materialAmounts.add(holder.num.getText().toString());
}
```

Above code in getView may be run many times. So, you can use HashMap instead of your materialNames and materialAmounts to avoid duplication.